# PostgresSQL - How to get a string instead of NULL when there is no value in left join?

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables that have list of workers and events.

When I'm trying to bring the list of ALL the workers with the current event that is still not finished , I either get an event name or NULL , but instead of null , I would like to get empty string because when I'm sending the result back to HTML , I get "NULL" on the screen.

I tried

```
select workers.id, workers.name , events.name 
from workers  left join events on events.workerid = workers.id
where events.isfinished = false;
```

results is :

```
1   Dave      NULL
2   Charlie   Event 2
3   Steve     Event 3
```

My Tables

```
Workers    
Id      Name
-----------------
1       Dave
2       Charlie
3       Steve

Events
Id     Description     workderId     isFinished
------------------------------------------------------
1       Event 1            1             true
2       Event 2            2             false
3       Event 3            3             false

What should my sql be in order to get empty string or different value instead of NULL ?
```

Comment: Use `coalesce`. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL

Comment: awesome , I tried it before and got weird error message regarding "anonymous  function".. but now it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `COALESCE()`, something like this:

```
SELECT workers.id, workers.name AS worker, COALESCE(events.name, '') AS event
FROM workers
  LEFT JOIN events ON events.workerid = workers.id
WHERE events.isfinished = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT
    w.id,
    w.name AS workers_name,
    COALESCE(e.name, '') AS events_name   -- or replace with some other string value
FROM workers w
LEFT JOIN events e
   ON e.workerid = w.id
WHERE
    e.isfinished = false;
```

Note that your current query is selecting two columns both of which are called `name`.  I aliased them to different things, to keep the result set readable.